# ssrs len() with the datasetname

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following issue :

This works:

> `LEN(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value) = 0`

This or this , do not work :

> `LEN(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value, "DataSetDirigeants") = 0`
>
> `(LEN(First(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value, "DataSetDirigeants")) = 0`

Why and is there a way to deal with this SSRS limitation (if it is a limitation)?

Thanks

Comment: Try `LEN(First(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value, "DataSetDirigeants")) = 0`.  I believe that when you use a dataset designation you have to use one of the built in aggregate or singular SSRS functions.

Comment: Do you want to get the characters lenght of a field in a specific dataset?

Comment: Hi @Kidiskidvogingogin I tried that already. It did not work

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work"? Share error or returned value.

Comment: Can you show more of the statement? Are you using this in an `IIf` statement? I'm assuming this is some part of a conditional statement.

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin where is my gun? Give me a gun please for my stupidity. I tried and tried and nothing appeared. I put the question in stack and suddenly `(LEN(First(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value, "DataSetDirigeants")) = 0` is doing the trick   -_-

Comment: Hi @alejandrozuleta I had an error saying there was a missing `)` -_-

Comment: It would be nice if SSRS would highlight matching parentheses.  It would certainly make issues like this a lot easier to find and fix. You do still have an extra leading parenthesis in your comment code.  The leading parenthesis before `LEN(...)` is not matched.

Comment: Indeed @Kidiskidvogingogin.  SSRS is giving me headaches sometimes ... why don't you put the answer , Sir? The point are yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to wrap the dataset field in an 
[SSRS Aggregate Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255275.aspx).
Something like `LEN(First(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value, "DataSetDirigeants"))` should work.

As to your question of why `LEN(Fields!LIBEL_FONCTION.Value, "DataSetDirigeant"))` will not work, I believe it has to do with [Expression Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256(v=sql.130).aspx). Without using an aggregate of some sort, SSRS cannot know which single value to use from your dataset.

**TL;DR**
You're trying to define your Expression Scope, but you're not narrowing it down to a single item and SSRS doesn't know how to handle it.